# error via using .map to create grouping age (dataframe)

Tags: python, dataframe, grouping

I just have data that have different age and I want to group them in new column in order to plot a graph

I try `df2["Aging Group"] = df2["Aging Group"].map({"20-39":0,"40-59":1,"60-79":2,"80+":3})`
but the error orrured, any know what wrong? , thx
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Loks like you are looking for [Pandas Apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

```
 dictionary = {"20-39":0,"40-59":1,"60-79":2,"80+":3}
 df2["Aging Group"] = df2["Aging Group"].apply(lambda x: dictionary.get(x))
```